# Interact with canvas shapes KineticJS

Tags: html, html5-canvas, kineticjs

I am currently using Kinetic.js to create a simple canvas, with 3 buttons which, using Kinetic to add a dragable shape to the canvas; one button for a circle, one for a square, one for rectangles.

What I know want to do is be able to interact with each shape with a context menu, I can do this using a JQuery plugin and have it working fine on static divs.

**Question: I am clueless as to interact with a shape on a canvas, is this possible?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can listen for the click event and then use the event to determine if the right-button (context button) has been pressed:

```
myShape.on('click', function(event){ 
   if (event.which== 3) {
      // trigger your context menu here
   }
});
```